# How can I add collisions to a list of objects (circles) in tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, collision-detection, tkinter-canvas

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import random

class SpaceField:
    def __init__(self):

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Asteriods")
        self.canvas = self.canvas_display() #creates canvas
        self.asteriods = self.asteriod_creation_seperation() #creates asteroids 
        self.active = True
        self.move_active()  #Moves asteroids 
        self.canvas.update()
```

```
    def asteriod_creation_seperation(self): #creation of multple asteriods
        asteriod_spacingx = random.randint(1,800)
        asteriod_spacingy = random.randint(1,800)
        asteriod_list = list() # could list([])
        for i in range(15):
            asteriod = self.canvas.create_oval( 30, 50 , 80 , 100 , tags="asteriod", width=2, outline="white")
            asteriod_list.append("asteriod")
            self.canvas.move(asteriod, asteriod_spacingx, asteriod_spacingy)
            asteriod_spacingx = random.randint(1,500)
            asteriod_spacingy = random.randint(1,500)
            print(asteriod_spacingy)
        return asteriod_list
```

Asteroid Creation. Creates asteroids and gives them random positions.

```
    def asteriod_update(self):  #asteriods movement method #MAin problem
            x12 = 1
            self.canvas.move("asteriod", 3, x12)
            pos = self.canvas.coords("asteriod")
            print(pos)
            if (pos)[2] > 500:
                x12 *= 5
```

I think this is where I need to add the collision detection. I just have no idea how to combine the lists of the circles and the collisions.

```
    def move_active(self): #Basically a true loop
        if self.active:
            self.asteriod_update()
            self.window.after(40, self.move_active)
```

```
def canvas_display(self):  #canvas
    canvas = Canvas(self.window, width=500, height=400, background='black')
    canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
    canvas.update()
    return canvas
```

Canvas display nothing special

```
    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpaceF = SpaceField()
    SpaceF.run()
```

Comment: what are you trying to collide those asteroids with (usually circle collision is detected by measuring if the distance between the centres of those circles is equal or less than the sum of their radiuses)? also `x12 *= 5` does nothing because that variable is local and gets garbage collected or you haven't shown some code, btw, you should provide a [mre] (that is also in one piece)

Comment: I want to collide the asteroids with the canvas boundaries. Like if the canvas is 600 pixels wide I want the asteroid to bounce back when it hits the limit. Sorry I am new at stack overflow, thank you I will try it. @Matiiss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asteroids is a classic game but there were a number of problems in your code. The main one was calling `move_active` during initialization. This prevented the code from completing its `mainloop` initialization.

The other problem was the `asteroid_update` method that basically didn't do anything, also using `tags` to control all asteroids didn't work either.

Everything else was OK, although you might consider using polygons.

Here is one way to produce a bouncing objects program. I've inserted remarks that describe the methods used.

Objects change the speed and direction when they hit the boundary so their trajectories are randomized.

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randint as rnd

class SpaceField:
    def __init__(self):

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Asteriods")
        # Define canvas size and active flag
        self.wide, self.high, self.active = 500, 400, True
        self.canvas_display()
        self.asteriod_creation_seperation()

    def asteriod_creation_seperation(self):
        self.asteroids, self.speed = [], []
        size, radius = 50, 25
        for i in range(15):
            spacex = rnd(size, self.wide - size)
            spacey = rnd(size, self.high - size)
            self.asteroids.append( # Store oval item id
                self.canvas.create_oval(
                    spacex, spacey, spacex+size, spacey+size,
                    width=2, tags = "asteriod", outline = "white"))
            self.speed.append((rnd(1,4),rnd(1,4))) # Store random speed x, y

    def asteriod_update(self): # MAIN DRIVER: Work on ALL asteroids
        for i, a in enumerate(self.asteroids):
            xx, yy = self.speed[i] # get speed data
            x, y, w, h = self.canvas.coords(a)
            # check for boundary hit then change direction and speed
            if x < 0 or w > self.wide:
                xx = -xx * rnd(1, 4)
            if y < 0 or h > self.high:
                yy = -yy * rnd(1, 4)
            # Limit max and min speed then store it
            self.speed[i] = (max( -4, min( xx, 4)), max( -4, min( yy, 4 )))
            self.canvas.move(a, xx, yy) # update asteroid position

    def move_active(self):
        if self.active:
            self.asteriod_update()
            self.window.after(40, self.move_active)

    def canvas_display(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(
            self.window, width = self.wide,
            height = self.high, background = "black")
        self.canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")

    def run(self): # Begin asteroids here so that mainloop is executed
        self.window.after(200, self.move_active)
        self.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpaceF = SpaceField()
    SpaceF.run()
```